# Vuejs - Change selected options in select from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

How do I change selected options from the outside?

I have a multiple select and the user can click on the "All" button to select all the options.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafi16d/nqxa0g2m/).

I've tried to use the jQuery function "prop", but it only works visually; it doesn't change the Vue data.

```
$('option', '#filter-accountexpl').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using jQuery to do this.

You can select all of your options this way.

```
this.vaccountsexpl = Object.keys(this.accountsexpl)
```

You can select none of your options this way.

```
this.vaccountsexpl = []
```

You can select any list of your options this way.

```
this.vaccountsexpl = [129,132,133]
```

Here is your fiddle [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/nqxa0g2m/5/).

Vue is driven by data.